# What does the get method do in scala?

Tags: scala

```
post("/api/v1/multi_preview/create"){
    val html = getParam("html").get
    val subject = getParam("subject").get
 }
```

I want to know what exactly the .get method does in scala. getParam() is already returning the parameters to the post hit . I know that .get will make it easier as we dont have to "match" to check for null values as it will automotically thrown an exception in the former case.
Is there more to it than meets the eye?

Comment: I think you should really consider if getting runtime-exceptions is in any way acceptable for your application. The Option type is there to help make fault-tolerant code easier to implement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's usually  a function on `Option`s (i.e. `Some` or `None`). It gets you the contained element if it exists, otherwise it throws a `NoSuchElementException`.

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html

```
scala> val x:Option[Int] = Some(42)
x: Option[Int] = Some(42)

scala> x.get
res2: Int = 42

scala> None.get
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:322)
  ... 32 elided
```

As a side note, you should try to avoid using `get` because it lands you back in the land of null-pointer exceptions. Instead, try to use `getOrElse`, or continue to use your `Option` value through higher-order functions like `map`, `filter`, `fold`, `reduce` etc.

Here is an example of how you can use it to your advantage:

```
scala> def foo(opt:Option[Int]) = opt map (_+2) filter (_%2 == 0) map (_+1)
foo: (opt: Option[Int])Option[Int]

scala> foo(Some(40))
res4: Option[Int] = Some(43)

scala> foo(Some(41))
res5: Option[Int] = None

scala> foo(None)
res6: Option[Int] = None
```

You can just pretend that the value is always specified if you don't "touch" it directly.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that's some `Scalatra` related code, if that's the case, `getParam` return an [Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option). `Option`s are a wrapper around types that allow you to avoid having to check for `null`s (and other kind of utilities too), in fact a value wrapped in an `Option` can be `Some`, in which case you can use get to access the value, e.g.

```
val someString = Option("some text")
println(someString.get) // prints "some text"
```

Or can be a `None` in which case when calling `get` you get an exception, wether a value is a `Some` or `None` can be determined via param match

```
someOption match {
   case Some(value) => doSomething(value)
   case None => doSomethingElse()
}
```

Or using `isDefined` which returns true if it's `Some`, false if it's `None`.

Note that your code could throw exceptions since you call `get` without knowing if it's a `Some` or `None`, you should use `getOrElse` which returns the value the Option holds if there's any, or a default specified parameter:

```
val someNone = Option(null)
println(someNone.getOrElse("some default")) // prints "some default"
```